# In Jmeter Transaction Controller is executing more than thread count

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I have 3 thread groups(3 scenarios in ultimate thread group) for one test plan where i am distributing load among those. for example 12 users i am distributing 4 users for each thread group.Here i have multiple doubts where i am expecting bit more clarification.

1) each scenario has login transaction in a flow.is it possible to make one transaction for all the scenarios?
2) it is regarding load testing where i am distributing the load with below scenario.

```
  Total no of scenarios=3(ultimate thread groups where they contains multiple transaction controllers)
  Total no of users=10
  Ultimate thread group 1 scenario= 4 users(thread count)
  Ultimate thread group 2 scenario= 3 users(thread count)
  Ultimate thread group 3 scenario= 3 users(thread count)

  ramp up=150 sec,
  steady period=600 sec,
  ramp down=150 sec (Total duration 15 min) configured for each thread group.
```

For thread group scenario 1 thread users are 4.so i can expect the transactions under that can execute 4 times randomly. 
But in listener i am able to see that the transactions are executing more than 4 times(nearly 20 times that are getting executed which are fail due to lack of test data where i am providing test data foe only 4 users for this scenario).

Can any one please tell me where exactly i am doing mistake and how can i correct it myself?[Please find below screen shots for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEwj6.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Ultimate Thread Group (see: https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=UltimateThreadGroup) runs for 15 minutes. That will mean that 4 threads will run for 15 minutes before being shutdown. So from you information I guess a typical thread runs through your scenario in about 3,75min (225s). So when that thread finishes a new one will start and run your scenario again and again, until the 15min limit is reached.
If you want to run them only once I suggest to use the basic Thread Group, with 4 threads and no looping (loop count = 1).